# check unzip -t result

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I was wondering how I'd get the result of `unzip -t file.zip` so I could use it within an IF statement

At the moment I've got

```
if [ unzip -t "$file.zip" ]
then
#proceed with script
else
echo "Zip file is not ready"
fi
```

I've also tried `if [! unzip -t "$file.zip" ]` but I was wondering if there was a way to make sure the file is valid before continuing with the script.

I'm on a fairly simple web server, I don't think gzip is running and I can't use lsof to find out if the file is still being written to.

Any point in the right direction would be great. I've searched google and these forums but have had no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
if [ unzip -t "$file.zip" ]
```

With:

```
if unzip -t "$file.zip"
```

Or, if you prefer quiet:

```
if unzip -t "$file.zip" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The above should work on any POSIX shell.  If you use `bash` and prefer brevity even at the cost of portability, the above can be simplified to:

```
if unzip -t "$file.zip" &>/dev/null
```

#### Discussion

The command `[`, also known as the `test` command, is used to set an exit code according to some conditions, such as whether a file exists or a string is empty.  There is no need for the `test` command here.  `unzip` itself sets an appropriate exit code that can be used by the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll accept your answer when it allows. Ah I got confused with testing if it's valid etc, not really great with this. Thank you again.